# Will my TV block my wireless router signal?

Tags: router, wireless-router, tv, interference

I have a flat screen LED TV on a shelf, and I'd like to put my wireless router behind it to save space, and to hide the router for a clean look. Will the TV's field interfere with the wireless signal?

Comment: You mean, will the wireless router signals have trouble passing through the TV to devices in front of the TV?  Yes.

Comment: my guess would be betwen "not to any noticeable degree" and "no".

Comment: I'd say probably yes. I wouldn't be surprised if the TV has lots of internal shielding which could block the signal from the router. I've seen some TVs which had shielding all around the back of the screen and that could be a problem for WiFi signal.

Comment: Both of the above. the quantity of effect it will have would vary from minimal negative effect, to less than minimal positive effect depending on many factors. Like the framework that holds the pannel which can be a full sheet of metal. A Led backlight model could have less interferance for it, and a CCT curcuit could add tiny bits of interferance, depending on close proximity , other curcuits poorly sheilded in the monitor could add very minor interferance.  The thing to do would be the same as it ever was, find your worst reception point, and adjust it while seeing how it negotiates.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for all of your suggestions. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an Atom based PC (Zotac) that mounts to a VESA mount on the back of my Plasma TV.  It uses wireless to connect to the router and another PC on a different floor of the house in opposite corners. I have had no problem with the wireless signal in the 8 months it has been in place.

Naturally, TVs an be different as can the wireless setup.  Your results may be different but worth trying

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have proven that my TV, even turned off, blocks the signal from a Wifi router

With the router behind my TV I get '0 Bars' signal in a certain room of my house, and a packet loss in the region of 25% on a simple ping.

Moving the router forward 8 inches so it is in front of the TV, I get 3 bars, and no packet loss.